# CasperJS and sending text to TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, casperjs

I'm trying to send text to Tinymce but this.click and this.sendKeys obviously wont work for that.

Here is the tinymce HTML from the page I'm trying to post to.

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('post_two').onLoad.dispatch();" contenteditable="true" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding-bottom: 50px;" dir="ltr"></body>
```

Any suggestions here, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the ideal world you would be using `tinyMCE.editors[0].setContent("your text")`, but from what I saw when using [casper visual debugger](https://github.com/maciejjankowski/casperView) tinymce iframe wouldn't load when the callback is fired. You need to call `casper.wait()` for couple seconds to let the iframe load (or watch for iframe's resource url being loaded)

the workaround I used is to bypass form validation or sending `FormData` object with AJAX:

```
  var formData = new FormData(document.forms[1]);
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://...',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false, //'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
          alert(data);
      }
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your workaround, can you please elaborate on where this code goes. When can I use the workaround? *I'm not going to use it, I'm just asking for clarification.*

Comment: I assumed you want to submit the form at the end. so the workaround is to fill corresponding form field and send form with ajax instead of regular submit action.

Answer (score 1):

I found work around. I this.click on another element in the page, and then send TAB events until I get to the tinymce. Not ideal, but it works

Comment: How do you check that you are at tinymce already when you TAB multiple times? Can you provide some code?

Comment: I don't know if I'm at the tinymce. I test the workflow on an actual browser manually, but if the site changes the structure of the web page, then the script will stop working. That's why the solution is not ideal. So basically, I select an element on the page that I can reference using this.click("some_selector"); then Tab to the tinymce with this.page.sendEvent('keypress', 16777217);

Answer (score 0):

Below the body tag you will see a `textarea` element. So just use the `this.fill(form,inputs including textarea,SendYEsOrNo)` to check if the form works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however, below the body tag there is only the following. <p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>  When you type in the browser, the <br.. disappears and the text I am typing is put in its place instead.

Comment: Did you search for "Textarea"? Strange if it is not in the dom.